# Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry" Axiom I, 6?

Tags: geometry

That axiom states: "**If two planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have a point A in common, then they have at least a second point B in common.**"

I don't understand this; if two planes have a point in common, doesn't that mean they intersect in a line and therefore have an infinite number of points in common?

How is it possible for two planes to have only 2 points in common, for example?

If it's not possible, isn't the phrasing ambiguous since "at least a second point in common." seems to suggest that exactly two points is a possibility?

Comment: It does not state that they do not have more than 2 points in common.

Comment: @ChantryCargill, but then why write "at least" and not say that they have an infinite number of points in common? The phrasing is ambiguous, suggesting there might be cases with only two points in common between the planes.

Comment: I have not looked through the book, but I would suggest that the axiom can be used to relate the definition of a line to the intersection of 2 planes. A line can be defined by 2 points. Also, as an axiom, it's probably a good idea to only state as little as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how much to say. Hilbert follows a *synthetic* tradition; that is, no numbers are introduced. There are relations, one segment is shorter, or the same length, or longer than another segment. There is no guarantee that a line has more than two points, for example.

If you get through the whole thing, you will find that numbers are created for the non-Euclidean plane, in the construction called the "field of ends."

As you write that you are self-studying, I recommend a more modern treatment, Hartshorne *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond* gives a pretty complete version of Hilbert's axioms, with far more detailed explanation than the original.

You might learn something by looking at finite projective planes. In fact, I would recommend projective geometry as a better first course in axiomatic geometry. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_field_planes

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely check it out.